# Vagrant and Ansible facts

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

Is it possible to have Ansible display [facts](http://docs.ansible.com/setup_module.html#setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) about a Vagrant box?

The [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) uses

```
ansible hostname -m setup
```

even if I connect with the Vagrant user I would still need the SSH key to connect to the Vagrant box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved, [Using Vagrant and Ansible, Running Ansible Manually](http://docs.ansible.com/guide_vagrant.html#running-ansible-manually)

```
ansible -i hosts default -m setup --user vagrant \
    -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory \
    --private-key=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it locally in vagrant instead.

```
ansible all -i localhost, -c local -m setup
```